# Gradle version dependency control

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have several version with the following version number
2.2.0.0, 2.2.0.1, 2.2.0.2 and 2.2.0

I want to get the 2.2.0 instead of 2.2.0.1.

What i mean is the + just look for the minor version and that digit only without looking forward to the next digit. So that 2.2.+ will only look for 2.2.0,2.2.1,2.2.2..etc...
and won't look for 2.2.0.1, 2.2.0.2...etc.

Is it possible to make the + sign just map like that?

I mean the + sign just look for the third digit and the forth digit will be ignored.

```
dependencies {
    prepare group: "com.abc.efg", name: "app1",version: "2.2.+"
    prepare group: "com.abc.efg", name: "app2",version: "2.2.+"
    prepare group: "com.abc.efg", name: "app3", version: "2.2.+"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I have read this page, I am not sure if i can write my own version pattern matcher.http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/version-matchers.html

It will be great if anyone can share their experiences. Thanks

Comment: you said: I want to get the 2.2.0 instead of 2.2.0.1. then why not try dependencies { prepare "com.abc.efg:app1:2.2.0" }

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies and http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_does_dynamic_dependency_resolution_decide_which_version_to_use might help.

Comment: because i want dynamic version control. So if i specific exact version, it won't help in my case. Thanks for your help. I have already read those information.